# Disable hardware back button

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to develop hybrid mobile app. My app contains loading app (`load.js`) and core app (`core.js`). When the app first boot up, it will load `load.js` and show the login screen. Once user login, it will connect to the server and load `core.js`. These 2 JS are running independently and can't communicate directly. `load.js` is only use on startup, after that it is "sleeping" at the back.

This kind of method works great and fine, except with the hardware back button. If the `load.js` is loaded with ionic, then when user click on hardware back button, the app will exit instantly. I tried with `$ionicPlatform.offHardwareBackButton()`, but didn't work.

So, is there a way to remove hardware back button on `load.js` without removing ionic from it?

Comment: Can you please mark an answer as 'accepted' if it solved your problem? :)

Comment: @user1995781: have you solved the issue? looking for similar implementation of `Carl`'s answer but I'm not able to get the desired end result :(

Answer (score 1):

This is the service I use to disable the back button: 
https://gist.github.com/mircobabini/689955216a036544d594

```
.service( 'HardwareBackButtonManager', function($ionicPlatform){
  this.deregister = undefined;

  this.disable = function(){
    this.deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }, 101);
  }

  this.enable = function(){
    if( this.deregister !== undefined ){
      this.deregister();
      this.deregister = undefined;
    }
  }
  return this;
})

// usage
.controller( 'YourController', function( 'HardwareBackButtonManager' ){
    HardwareBackButtonManager.disable();

    // re-enable it when you want,
    HardwareBackButtonManager.enable();
})
```